# How to read from resource file, after linking it with unit module?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, embedded-resource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read from Resource file in delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021066/how-to-read-from-resource-file-in-delphi-7)

Implementation:

```
{$R *.dfm}
{$R 'stuff.res' 'stuff.rc'}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var 
  vExeFile: string;
  RS: TResourceStream;
begin
  RS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'ExeTest', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    vExeFile := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'tmp.exe';
    RS.SaveToFile(vExeFile);
  finally
    RS.Free;
  end;    
end;
```

I have tried above code but it shows **Resource ExeTest not found**. I have tried both with TResourceStream.Create() and TResourceStream.CreateById() but could not read.

Comment: Please show the actual .rc file.

Comment: clearly that module doesn't contain the resource. The error message is clear. Question is why not?